# Upload docx file downloaded from google drive using paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I want to upload docx file downloaded from google drive using **gem paperclip** but I am getting **Invalid content type error**. Below is my code

```
has_attached_file :initial_document
validates_attachment :initial_document, content_type: {content_type: %w(image/jpeg image/jpg image/png application/pdf application/msword application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document)}
```

I am able to upload file created from ms word but not from google drive.
During debugging, I found that the content type of the .docx file is **application/zip** I am using **Rails 5.0 and paperclip 5.1**

Comment: Are you sure its `application/zip`? If so just add it to the `content_type`

Comment: yeah, its application.zip , I have allowed application.zip but while downloading I received the same file without any extension

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in below line,

```
validates_attachment :initial_document, content_type: {content_type:
```

here, content_type is repeated, which is not correct syntax.

replace above with

```
validates_attachment :initial_document, 
  content_type: %w(
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
    application/pdf
    application/msword
    application/word
    application/x-msword
    application/x-word
    application/zip
    text/plain
    image/jpeg 
    image/jpg 
    image/png 
  )
```

Here **application/zip** is important for the .docx file

I have tested with above changes and document object is created successfully as below

```
    #<Document:0x0d0bd8f0> {
                                :id => 1,
           :document_list_file_name => "sample-document.docx",
        :document_list_content_type => "application/zip",
           :document_list_file_size => 12711,
          :document_list_updated_at => Wed, 19 Sep 2018 11:56:02 UTC +00:00
    }
```

Hope, this will solve your issue.

Comment: My syntax is also correct, when I add application/zip, it works but after downloading, it gives the file without any extension